How to filter the opportunity "owner ID" field in a report using Apex?
When building a report programatically using Apex, setting up a filter "Owner ID equals " by using a ReportFilter (from the Reports namespace), what is the name of the column for the owner ID on the standard opportunity object?
I tried the following without success:
Reports.ReportFilter ownerFilter = new Reports.ReportFilter(
    'OPPORTUNITY_OWNER',
    'equals',
    UserInfo.getUserId(),
    Reports.ReportFilterType.fieldValue,
    'Opportunity'
);

Running this for an existing opportunity report (that doesn't have that filter already) gives me the following execution error:

reports.InvalidFilterException: [For the filter 1: Specify a valid filterable column because OPPORTUNITY_OWNER is invalid.]

I also tried OwnerId, OWNER_ID and OWNER and the error message is the same. So what's the exact name to use to filter by the owner's ID?

According to page 6 in the Reports API Winter 25 documentation, the opp owner field name is  FULL_NAME.  That looks crazy and I haven't tested it myself.

Exactly! Which begs the question: what if there are two users with the same name in the org?

By the way: thank you for that useful link!

If you try to add opportunity owner as report filter, the list of suggested fields are opportunity owner, alias, email, phone, etc. but none is Owner Id.
So filtering by OwnerId is not allowed in standard report builder which may explain why this is not allowed in apex.
Adding opportunity owner as filter in the report builder, indeed resolves column name as FULL_NAME (as mentioned David Cheng in the comments) and this is also confirmed when debugging the report filter getColumn() in apex.
Though not an ideal solution, but a workaround will be to add a custom formula field on opportunity object, OppyOwnerId__c that returns the opportunity owner Id.
Then filter the report using the formula as follows :
Reports.ReportFilter ownerFilter = new Reports.ReportFilter(
       'Opportunity.OppyOwnerId__c', 
       'equals',
       UserInfo.getUserId(),
       Reports.ReportFilterType.fieldValue,
       'Opportunity'
);

